# why I am not receiving any firebug console response stuff?

Tags: php, jquery

I have this ajax call in my external javascript file, and I am not getting any stuff from the firebug console, here's my code

```
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "classes/ajax.registerpopup.php",
      timeout: 8000,
      data: "userid="+userid+"&resumetitle="+resumetitle+"&resumeintro="+resumeintro+
            "&name="+name+"&dob="+dob+"&contacttel1="+contacttel1+"&contacttel1type="+contacttel1type+
            "&contacttel2="+contacttel2+"&contacttel2type="+contacttel2type+"&contacttel3="+contacttel3+
            "&contacttel3type="+contacttel3type+"&primaryemail="+primaryemail+"&secondaryemail="+secondaryemail+
            "&skype="+skype+"&facebook="+facebook+"&linkedin="+linkedin+"&twitter="+twitter+
            "&messenger="+messenger+"&yahoo="+yahoo+"&aol="+aol+"&summaryofpositionsought="+
            summaryofpositionsought+"&summaryofskills="+summaryofskills+"&gender="+gender,
      success: function(msg){
          if(msg == "success"){
            alert(msg);
           $('form#wsrecruitcvhead').fadeOut("normal",function(){
           $('div.successpost').fadeIn(1000);
          });
          } else {
            alert(msg);
          }
      },
      });
      return false;
         }
```

here's my php code

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO wsrecruitcvhead VALUES($userid,NULL,NULL,'$resumetitle','$resumeintro','$name','$dob','$contacttel1','$contacttel1type',
'$contacttel2','$contacttel2type','$contacttel3','$contacttel3type','$primaryemail','$secondaryemail','$skype','$facebook','$linkedin','$twitter',
'$messenger','$yahoo','$aol','$summaryofpositionsought','$summaryofskills','$gender',NOW(),NULL)";


if(mysql_query($result)){
  echo "success";
} else {
  echo "error".mysql_error();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with *firebug console response stuff* ? What do you expect?

Comment: Make sure the firebug is `ON` when you make ajax call on the page.

Comment: I love all the validation and variable checking for your SQL Insert, no possible way for SQL injection/attack here.

Comment: i didn't pasted all the code..ofcourse it has validation stuffs... @Felix Kling, I was expecting the "success" to appear at the response tab of the firebug console during the ajax call, but it appears empty

Answer (score 5):

- Using `alert` won't show nothing on your firebug console, you must use `console.log`
- `success` parameter on `$.ajax` only works if no server errors occur, so if there is an error in your PHP code this method won't be called

Update: 
Just to share some jQuery experience, given all your form fields have a `name` attribute you could use `$.serialize` to build this `param1=value1&param2=value2` string. Check this link: http://api.jquery.com/serialize.

Answer (score 2):

This could be due to the fact that your call does not succeed. Have you tried adding:

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert('error');
}
```

to your ajax call?Also bear in mind that to see stuff in the firebug console you must use console.log or console.dir. You could also check the NET log to see if the call succeeded